# Верстка наложенных объектов

Tags: html, css

Имееться вот такой вот блок :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не очень понимаю как его сверстать . Хотел сделать через флексы , а потом просто использовать минусовый margin,но тогда будет очень проблемно центрировать картинки 556x300.
Вопрос: В какую сторону мне посмотреть ? Что тут можно использовать?

Comment: Центральная колонка как задумаете, а верхние блоки через `position: absolute` (а у родительского обязательно `position: relative`), и через `left`, `right`, `top` подвигать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На мой взгляд, всё очень просто, с помощью позиционирования `position` : `relative` и `absolute`. И не нужно изобретать велосипед. Пример ниже. Размеры элементов, а также значения их положения относительно родительского элемента несложно заменить на нужные под себя.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item__abs {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.item__abs:nth-child(1) {
  top: -20px;
  left: -200px;
}

.item__abs:nth-child(2) {
  top: 80px;
  right: -200px;
}

.item__abs:nth-child(3) {
  top: 180px;
  left: -200px;
}

.item__abs:nth-child(4) {
  top: 280px;
  right: -200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="item__abs"></div>
  <div class="item__abs"></div>
  <div class="item__abs"></div>
  <div class="item__abs"></div>

  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>

</div>
```